# 256000 Bytes Limit of Python's SQLite3 Databases

Tags: python, sqlite

I have written a web crawler that does some online pre-processing and stores that data into a database. The database layout is quite simple, but let me outline it:

- Table `dispatched` lists items that were dispatched at a particular time, which is one of the columns. There are 15 other columns that describe the items: One of these is from type `TEXT` and the rest is from type `INT`.
- The table `missed` lists the time periods that the crawler failed to watch, e.g. because of network problems. It has 4 columns from type `INT` and 2 columns from type `TEXT`.

I left it run for many hours twice. Both times, the resulting database file had a total size of exactly 256000 bytes, at least according to `ls -l`. I have seen from the recorded data that regularly 1-3 items are recorded per minute, but starting from a particular time, there are no new items listed any more.

To me, this sounds as if there was a limitation that I hit. Given that the resulting database file size was exactly `1000 * 2^8` bytes both times, I would suspect that it is a limitation on the maximum database file size, but the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) doesn't say anything like that.

The moment that SQLite stopped appending new rows to the database, there were

- 5187 rows on `dispatched` and 3 rows on `missed` during the first run and
- 5212 rows on `dispatched` and 2 rows on `missed` during the second run.

I'm using the `sqlite3` module for Python 2.7. I appreciate any help that might point out what was going on, why SQLite stopped appending new rows after hitting 256000 bytes and how I could fix this.

---

**Update:** I've decided to add some snippets from my code.

The application consists of tasks that are scheduled and executed by a class named `Gatherer`. First, lets have a look at the task that is of interest here:

```
class ControlTask(Task):

    def __init__(self, player, scheduled_start):
        Task.__init__(self, scheduled_start)
        self.player = player

    def __str__(self):
        return u'CONTROL: player %d' % self.player.player_id

    def execute(self, gt):
        # [...]
        gt.dispatch(self.player)
        # [...]
```

The `Gatherer` calls `execute` on each task when the time has come, providing a reference to itself via the `gt` argument:

```
class Gatherer:

    def process_next_task(self):
        task = self.tasks.get()
        while True:
```

I can see those messages even after SQLite stop appending rows:

```
            print task.__str__()
```

But I do not see neither of the following error messages. Furthermore, *note that this loop won't exit until the task finishes without exceptions*:

```
            try:
                task.execute(self)
                break
            except engine.NetworkException:
                print 'NETWORK PROBLEM DETECTED. Reconnecting.'
                self.reconnect()
            except:
                print 'UNKNOWN EXCEPTION OCCURED. Reconnecting.'
                self.reconnect()

    def reconnect(self):
        # [...]
```

The `ControlTask` invokes `dispatch` on the `Gatherer`, which, in turn, writes the data that the task computed to the database:

```
    def dispatch(self, player):
        self.db_cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO dispatched VALUES
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''', (\
                None, player.deadline, player.age, player.tsi, \
                player.speciality, player.skills[0], player.skills[1], \
                player.skills[2], player.skills[3] , player.skills[4], \
                player.skills[5], player.skills[6], player.skills[7], \
                player.skills[8], player.skills[9], player.skills[10]))
        self.db.commit()
```

The `Gatherer` creates the database when it is instantiates and closes the database connection when it is garbage collected:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = Queue.PriorityQueue()

        self.db = sqlite3.connect('%s.db' % time.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'))
        self.db_cursor = self.db.cursor()

        self.db_cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dispatched (
            amount int, deadline int, age int, tsi int, speciality text,
            s1 int, s2 int, s3 int, s4 int, s5 int, s6 int,
            s7 int, s8 int, s9 int, s10 int, s11 int)''')

        self.db_cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS missed (
            missed_from int, missed_until int,
            min_age int, max_age int,
            min_lvl int, max_lvl int)''')

    def __del__(self):
        self.db.close()
```

And finally, here is the actual program:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    gt = Gatherer()

    tasks_processed = 0
    while True:
        print 'Starting %d. task while %d are enqueued:' % \
            (tasks_processed+1, gt.tasks.qsize())
        try:
            gt.process_next_task()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
        except:
            del gt
            raise
        tasks_processed = tasks_processed + 1
```

Comment: Did your code error?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Excuse me, but I don't understand your question. In case you meant whether I got any runtime errors: *No, I didn't get any runtime errors.*

Comment: Yes, I meant runtime errors, the max size for a sqlite database is 140 terabytes and number of max rows is 2^64  so I doubt the size is an issue.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, that's what I've read too. But I have no idea what it else could be.

Comment: OS level or file system problem?

Comment: @KlausD. Probably. I opened the database file from another Python script and appended 10k new rows, which worked fine. So maybe the database "connection" is timing out or something, although its still strange that it's happening right after 256000 bytes?

Comment: There is almost certainly something happening in your code that is causing the issue, how are you catching network and sqlite  errors?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I've added snippets from my code.

Comment: Try this:
`db = sqlite3.connect('filename.db', isolation_level=None)`

Comment: Also, that's a pretty unusual filename you're using. I'm not sure why it would matter, but you never know.. try getting rid of the spaces and punctuation and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Not a big fan of closing the database in `__del__` either. Actually, generally speaking you should almost never use `__del__` in Python: [del is not the opposite of init](http://www.algorithm.co.il/blogs/programming/python-gotchas-1-__del__-is-not-the-opposite-of-__init__/)

Comment: Thanks @bsa, for some reason the `isolation_level=None` fixed the problem :) I will accept your answer if you write one.